# MS graph api schema extension filter bug with outlook resources (messages, events, contacts)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When trying to filter for a custom created schema extension:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=(<schemaId>/<key> eq '<value>')
```

the error message we get is:

```
"message": "Could not find a property named 'e2_<ourTenantID>_<schemaId>' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event'"
```

The problem is that before performing search, the API prepends tenantID to schema ID, thus failing to recognize the property. It seems that graph API performs search using their own internal schema ID.

Interesting thing is, that when searching for a non-existing schema, the tenantID is not added.

The problem persists when testing to filter messages, events and contacts.

Our schema extension creation JSON:

```
{
    "description": "Extension to help avoid duplicates",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Contact",
        "Message",
        "Event"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "UniqueId",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ],
    "status": "InDevelopment",
    "owner": "<appID>",
    "id": "<name>",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.ComplexExtensionValue"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this appears a known limitation of the Outlook entity types (contact, event, message, or post) as stated by the documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#extensions.